# Issue while connecting localhost MySQL through Tableau?

Tags: mysql, tableau-api

I'm trying to connect the localhost MySQL through tableau on the MacOS but I am unable to connect and the Sign-In button is not actived.

**I have downloaded the driver for database so that I can connect Tableau to your data from tableau.**

Screenshot :

[image]

How to solve this :

Comment: 1) I'm afraid this is not the place to talk about this problem, try a forum that talks about Tableau-Mysql  2) no code, 3)  no information (TAbleau desktop ? server ? online ?) .

Comment: Please provide more details about the error and also check if the connection string you are providing is correct. For more info on MySQL connection strings here: https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_mysql.htm

Comment: Try typing `localhost` instead of the usual IP address. In MacOS only connection is possible through domain name. If you want to use IP address you will have to add the IP address to the system `hosts` file along with an alias.